# Using fgets and feof

Tags: c

Having simple text file like myfile1.txt:

```
cat myfile1.txt:

abc
```

and below code

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <errno.h>
# include <unistd.h>


char mybuffer[80] = "abc\n";
char* result = NULL;

int main() {
        FILE* pFile;
        pFile = fopen ("myfile1.txt", "r+");
        int c;

        if (pFile == NULL)
                perror ("Error opening file");
        else {
                result = fgets(mybuffer, 80, pFile);

                if (feof(pFile)) {
                        printf("fgets EOF");
                }

                fclose (pFile);
                return 0;
        }
}
```

Why doesn't the function `feof` returns nonzero while the end of the stream has been reached (`fgets` gets 3 chars "abc" and hits EOF)?

Comment: Because that's not how `feof` works. `feof` does not return true when reaching the end of the stream; it returns true after trying to read from the stream *after* it's already at the end. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong

Comment: @jamesdlin But wait, after calling `fgets` like above isn't the stream indead at the end?

Comment: After the `fgets` call above, the stream will be *at* the end, but `fgets` did not try to read *past* the end.

Answer (score 1):

Because `feof()` does not return true until an attempt to read past the end of the file.

Per the documentation:

> Checks whether the end-of-File indicator associated with stream is set, returning a value different from zero if it is.
>
> This indicator is generally set by a previous operation on the stream that attempted to read at or past the end-of-file.